# how can I replay guacamole replay file by html5

Tags: guacamole

I need to replay guacamole replay file by html5.

But the only thing I can do now is to use guacenc to convert the playback file into a video and play it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to build a [demo](https://github.com/TelDragon/guacamole/tree/master/java-demo) based on the secondary development of guacamole-example to realize the playback of the screen file.

Although I still don't know the principle of its implementation, it solves my problem very well.

I also tried the official demo, but there is a problem with maven dependencies.